# Remove items form an MFC Ribbon

Tags: mfc, ribbon

OK, here's the scenario: we have a file which determines which options will be present in an mfc ribbon depending on previously chosen criterias. So, if I have a button which opens a group of other buttons, do I have do delete the items from this group before deleting the main button? It looks like MainOption->sub1, sub2...

Comment: I don't know, but: 1) What happens if you do? and 2) What happens if you don't?

Comment: You got me :D OK, I'll check. I didn't want to because I'm not sure about the memory leaks but I'll see what happens.

Comment: So your *real* question is something like *"If I delete the main button, will it delete it's dependent buttons or will I get a memory leak?"*. If so, when you find out, post an answer yourself because that's useful info.

Comment: I can't find any info on the web. By some experimenting and reading in MSDN I found two methods: SetVisible(bool isVisible) and DestroyCtrl(). None of them did anything when I tried using them. DestroyCtrl is actually meant to be implemented by the developer but I can't find any suitable functions to call in it. SetVisible doesn't seem to work although I redraw the ribbon after calling it :/

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/414407/cmfcribbonbaseelement-setvisible-does-not-work And hereäs the answer...

Comment: I got a crazy idea - is it possible to edit the xml file in runtime and reload it?

Comment: Maybe, I don't know, but `CMFCRibbonBar` only seems to provide `LoadFromResource` to load XML, and you can't change the resources in an application while it's running. Maybe you could derive a class and hijack the same functionality though, it would be interesting to see.

Comment: I shall give it a try tomorow!

Comment: Just found this parser/editor: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24492/CXMLFile-A-Simple-C-XML-Parser I think it'll do the job. What I need is to modify the ribbon at startup, so editing the XML and then loading it should be fairly easy. I'll share the results :)

Comment: Nope, nope, nope! I completely forgot that the xml file is used as a resource, so I can't edit it on the fly :(

Comment: Looking at the source, there is an undocumented public function called `CMFCRibbonBar::LoadFromBuffer`, which takes an XML string as input. That should do the trick.

Comment: I already found a way to delete the buttons - find its index in the panel and then - thePanel.Remove(index)

Comment: OK, now I have to problems. 1 - when I remove a button, a gap remains where the button used to be. 2 - when the button is in a list(like a drop-down menu), it doesn't have a parentpanel and I can't seem to find any group which could provide me with a remove() method :/

Comment: So, here's the solution for anyone with the same problem: 1 - Find the button's index in the panel; 2 - thePanel.Remove(index); 3 - theRibbon.AdjustSizeImmediate(); 4 - theRibbon.Redraw(); Cheers!